# Scrapy Pagination - Works for 2 pages but not after that

Tags: scrapy

I'm crawling cdw.com website. For a given URL, there are around 17 pages. The script that I have written is able t fetch data from Page 1 and Page 2. Spider closes on its own after giving result of first 2 pages. Please let me know, how can I fetch data for remaining 15 pages.

TIA.

```
import scrapy  
from cdwfinal.items import CdwfinalItem  
from scrapy.selector import Selector  
import datetime  
import pandas as pd  
import time  


class CdwSpider(scrapy.Spider):  
    name = 'cdw'
    allowed_domains = ['www.cdw.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.cdw.com/']
    base_url = 'http://www.cdw.com'


    def start_requests(self):
   
        yield scrapy.Request(url = 'https://www.cdw.com/search/?key=axiom' , callback=self.parse )
    
    def parse(self, response): 
    
        item=[]
        hxs = Selector(response)
        item = CdwfinalItem()
    

        abc = hxs.xpath('//*[@id="main"]//*[@class="grid-row"]')
    
        for i in range(len(abc)):
        
            try:
                item['mpn'] = hxs.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'search-results')]/div[contains(@class,'search-result')]["+ str(i+1) +"]//*[@class='mfg-code']/text()").extract()
            except:
                item['mpn'] = 'NA'

            try:
                item['part_no'] = hxs.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'search-results')]/div[contains(@class,'search-result')]["+ str(i+1) +"]//*[@class='cdw-code']/text()").extract()
            except:
                item['part_no'] = 'NA'

        
            
            yield item
    
        next_page = hxs.xpath('//*[@id="main"]//*[@class="no-hover" and @aria-label="Next Page"]').extract()
        if next_page:
            new_page_href =  hxs.xpath('//*[@id="main"]//*[@class="no-hover" and @aria-label="Next Page"]/@href').extract_first()
            new_page_url = response.urljoin(new_page_href)
            yield scrapy.Request(new_page_url, callback=self.parse, meta={"searchword": '123'})
```

**LOG:**

```
2023-02-11 15:39:55 [scrapy_user_agents.middlewares] DEBUG: Assigned User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36
2023-02-11 15:39:55 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.cdw.com/search/?key=axiom&pcurrent=3> (referer: https://www.cdw.com/search/?key=axiom&pcurrent=2) ['cached']
2023-02-11 15:39:55 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2023-02-11 15:39:55 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored csv feed (48 items) in: Test5.csv
2023-02-11 15:39:55 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 2178,
 'downloader/request_count': 3,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 68059,
 'downloader/response_count': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 3,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 1.30903,
 'feedexport/success_count/FileFeedStorage': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 11, 10, 9, 55, 327740),
 'httpcache/hit': 3,
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 384267,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 3,
 'item_scraped_count': 48,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 62,
 'log_count/INFO': 11,
 'log_count/WARNING': 45,
 'request_depth_max': 2,
 'response_received_count': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 3,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 11, 10, 9, 54, 18710)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `next_page` selector is failing to extract the information for the next page.  In general your selectors are more complicated then they need to be, for example you should be using relative `xpath` expressions in your for loop .

Here is an example that replicates the same behaviour as your spider except using much simpler selectors, and successfully extracts the results from all of the pages.

```py
import scrapy

class CdwSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'cdw'
    allowed_domains = ['www.cdw.com']
    custom_settings = {
            "USER_AGENT": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
         }

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url='https://www.cdw.com/search/?key=axiom' , callback=self.parse )

    def parse(self, response):
        for row in response.xpath('//div[@class="grid-row"]'):
            mpn = row.xpath(".//span[@class='mfg-code']/text()").get()
            cdw = row.xpath('.//span[@class="cdw-code"]/text()').get()
            yield {"mpn": mpn, "part_no": cdw}
        current = response.css("div.search-pagination-active")
        next_page = current.xpath('./following-sibling::a/@href').get()
        if next_page:
            new_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(new_page_url, callback=self.parse)
```

---

EDIT

The only non-default setting I am using is setting a the user agent.

I have made adjustments in the example above to reflect that.

Partial output:

```bash
2023-02-11 22:10:58 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2023-02-11 22:10:58 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 106555,
 'downloader/request_count': 41,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 41,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 1099256,
 'downloader/response_count': 41,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 41,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 22.968986,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 12, 6, 10, 58, 700080),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 7962149,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 41,
 'item_scraped_count': 984,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 1028,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'request_depth_max': 40,
 'response_received_count': 41,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 41,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 41,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 41,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 41,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 12, 6, 10, 35, 731094)}
2023-02-11 22:10:58 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. I tried with full code. However, still facing same issue. I get results only for 2 pages. May be this could be because of settings.  Can you please share setting you have used. Even trying the code that you wrote, still getting only 48 results or results from 2 pages only.
Adding full code to below answer.

Comment: That's odd. Even if I follow your edited code, I still get results from first 2 pages only. Could there be some other issue?

Comment: BTW, there's something even more peculiar. For different search words, number of pages extracted differ. Sometimes scrapy gives output from 4 pages, sometimes 3 or 2. The script doesn't seem to give constant result. Or, maybe website is not letting me scrape it. Any thoughts would be really helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. Unfortunately, it doesn't solve the issue for me.

Comment: And even copying nd pasting and running the code in my example doesn't help?  Can you post your scrapy output logs?